# Where to get samples of various PDF versions?

Tags: pdf, sample

I need sample PDFs of various versions (say 1.3 - 1.7) for testing purposes. Is there a place where I can download such samples?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the versions are somewhat 'incremental' so for example 1.4 is just a subset of 1.5. So If a PDF 1.5 doesn't have the "special features" of the 1.5 version vs the 1.4, then it will work even on an interpreter that only reads 1.4. As of the examples, I don't see where you can get them.

Comment: I'm testing a JVue customization and it behaves differently for 1.4 and 1.5

Comment: I ended up creating the samples myself using this PDF printer tool: http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php. It supports version 1.1 through 1.5 and the A-1b preservation version

Answer (score 1):

Most Adobe applications give you the option to select PDF version in their export. I have InDesign CS 5 now and it has 1.3-1.7.